# Time Machine not automatically deleting old backups

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, time-machine

My MacBook is currently using around 180GB of its internal drive. However, when I plug in my 250GB external drive to make backups of my Mac, I incessantly get the error "your backup drive does not have enough storage to perform the backup."

My backup drive still has 15GB free. From my understanding, older backups should be deleted to make space for newer ones. Is there any reason why Time Machine does not automatically delete the older backups to make space for the newer one?

Comment: It can't do it if any one file is bigger than the remaining space.

Comment: Does that mean that it makes the backup, and then deletes the old backups? How does it know how much free space to keep? Why doesn't TM go down to 1GB of free space ever? Is it possible for me to increase this "free space" limitation? Perhaps I can put a few 5GB dummy files inside my drive and delete them as is necessary?

Comment: tbh, I just think 250GB to backup 180GB doesn't leave enough room for manoeuvring. Personally I always go for at least twice the size, though often I maintain closer to 3x. That way, this never arises, no matter how big any single file.

Comment: When I click on the message, it actually says `The backup disk needs 38.45 GB for the backup but only 15.70 GB are available. Select a larger backup disk or make the backup smaller by excluding files.` So I guess this implies that I need free space as big as the *backup*, not as big as the biggest *file*. Unless that's what you meant by "file?" But yes, good point. I just thought it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I've seen it work for someone else by deselecting a Parallels VM file; gave it just enough room for manoeuvre, so always assumed it was the one large file blocking it.

Comment: I just scanned my disk and it doesn't look like I have any files larger than about 5GB anywhere. Perhaps the backup size decreased sufficiently when deselecting the Parallels VM (isn't that technically a folder bundle anyway?). I wish the real reason was documented somewhere though, but I couldn't find anything online (hence the question :P)

Comment: @SkeletonBow if you start up a VM in between backups, the virtual hard drive is modified. Time Machine can only back up whole files, which means the entire VM image is backed up. You can decrease this somewhat by using your VM application's "split into multiple files", though that might not make that much of a difference depending on how the VM's OS modifies files on its virtual HD. If you don't care about older versions of your VM, just go into the Time Machine UI, right click the VM bundle, and select "delete all backups of 'VM'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to delete your biggest backups (because Time Machine won't do it automatically), you can download [TimeTracker](https://www.charlessoft.com/), which will calculate the size of each backup, as well as show you which files are taking up space. From there, you can:

- decide to delete all backups of a file (by using the Time Machine UI and selecting "delete all backups of 'file'")
- Add the large file(s) to System Preferences > Time Machine > Options > Ignored files
- Delete an entire single backup by opening Terminal, typing `sudo tmutil delete`  and dragging, from finder, the backup you wish to delete. It should say something like this in the end: `sudo tmutil delete /Volumes/Backup\ Drive/Backups.backupdb/My\ Mac/2020-08-27-150021`