# Can't delete old Time Machine backups from Trash

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine, trash

I was trying to delete some old Time Machine backups from my backup drive. I am running into a few issues.

1. I tried the method outlined in [this article](https://www.imore.com/how-delete-older-time-machine-backups) of simply moving them to the trash. After I moved old backup folders to the trash, I tried deleting them from the trash, but got the following error:

[image]

2. I clicked "Get Info" and tried to set permissions for everyone from "Read Only" to "Read and Write." However, when trying to delete the folders I get the same issue.
3. I tried writing `rm -rf '/Volumes/MacBook Pro Backup/.Trashes/501/2020-07-03-051423'` in the terminal, but I get permission denied issues for all files in the folder. I am afraid to use `sudo` in front of the command in case this is not the correct way to delete the backups.
4. I tried finding the "Put back" option when right clicking the backup folder to put the backups back into the original location, but the option was not there.
5. I tried dragging and dropping the folders from the trash to the original backup location, but I get the following error:

[image]

Is there any way I can restore the old backups or remove them completely, without having to format my TM drive?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using `tmutil delete`.

First, I changed directory into where all the trashed backups were being kept:

```
cd /Volumes/MacBook\ Pro\ Backup/.Trashes/501
```

Then, I checked all the files in the directory to make sure I knew what I was deleting. This showed me a list of folders named by date:

```
sudo ls
```

Afterwards, I was able to use `tmutil delete` to delete all the backups:

```
sudo tmutil delete *
```

From now on, whenever I want to delete old backups, I will use `tmutil delete` on the backup folder.

Comment: Really, the correct way to delete backups is "don't".  Time Machine is perfectly capable of managing the backup drive on its own.

Comment: @MarcWilson Definitely, this would be my ideal scenario, but situations like [these sometimes arrive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/400122/197118), so I'm not quite sure one can claim that it's "perfectly capable of managing it on it's own" :P